# How to reference a variable from outside it's loop scope in Django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am sorry if the title is poorly phrased, but what i am trying to do is to use a variable that was in a for loop outside of it's scope ( in another part of the template )

here is my template:

```
<div class="inventory-content">
    <div class='category'>
        <div>Categories</div>
        <div class='category-checkbox'>
            {%for category in items%}
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{category.id}}" name="{{category.name}}" value="{{category.id}}">
            <label for="{{category.name}}"> {{category.name}}</label><br>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='items'></div>
    
</div>    

<script>
    $('.category-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          // Add the element to the div with an id identifier
          $('.items').append(`<div id="item_${this.id}">123</div>`);
        } else {
          // Remove the element from the div targeted by the id identifier
          $(`#item_${this.id}`).remove();
        }
      });
</script>
```

the view.py

```
def index(request,pk):
    vessel_id = Vessel.objects.get(id=pk)
    categories = vessel_id.category.all()
    item = categories.prefetch_related(
        'items')
    context ={"vessel_id":vessel_id,'items':item}
    return render(request,'inventory.html',context)
```

i want to be able to use that category variable so i can loop through all the items in that specific category and add them in the items `<div>`, if there is a better way to do this please guide me !

Comment: Update question with views

Comment: @Ahtisham i included it

Comment: Since category is in loop it would be many categories which category you want to access outside the loop ?

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to clarify that it's a loop of checkbox, and i have a jquery that will append an element inside that items div on (checked) i will edit the whole template now @Ahtisham

Comment: I think you are already adding it to items with jQuery what is the issue then ?

Comment: I am not sure how to append the items of that specific category tho i am new to programming so i thought if there is a way i can reference that variable then i can append it in the jquery but i am not sure how to get it from outside the scope loop@Ahtisham

Comment: Try replacing `.click(function()` with `.on('click', function()` and then do hard reload.

Comment: @Ahtisham that worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `click` with `on` event as you are dynamically adding elements like this:

```
$('.category-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    // rest of your code
});
```